# ckeckbox validation multiple divs

Tags: javascript

Let me explain the problem i have:

I have for example 3 radio buttons and when i click 1 radio button there are 2,3 or 4 divs that are showing depending on the radio button i choose

```
<input type="radio" name="reason" id="1" value="1" class="trigger" data-target=".term1, .term2, .term3" />
<label for="1">reason1</label> 

<input type="radio" name="reason" id="2" value="2" class="trigger" data-target=".term1" />
<label for="1">reason2</label> 

<input type="radio" name="reason" id="3" value="3" class="trigger" data-target=".term1, .term2" />
<label for="1">reason3</label> 



<div class="term1">
<input type="checkbox" name="term1" value="1" id="term1" /><label for="term1" class="termlabel">term1</label>
</div>

<div class="term2">
<input type="checkbox" name="term2" value="1" id="term2" /><label for="term2" class="termlabel">term2</label>
</div>

<div class="term3">
<input type="checkbox" name="term3" value="1" id="term3" /><label for="term3" class="termlabel">term3</label>
</div>
```

The radio and checkboxes are putted into a form where there is a javascript check onsubmit of that form.

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="frm" onsubmit="return validate();">
```

Here is my javascript file that i have made.

```
function validate()
{
   if( document.frm.reason.value == "" )
   {
     alert( "Please provide your reason of visit!" );
     return false;
   }

   if( document.frm.reason.value == "1" && document.getElementById("term1").checked == true && document.getElementById("term2").checked == true && document.getElementById("term3").checked == true )
   {
   return( true );
   }
   else 
   {
   alert( "Please accept all of the terms!" );
   return false;
   }

   if( document.frm.reason.value == "2" && document.getElementById("term1").checked == true )
   {
   return true ;
   }
   else 
   {
   alert( "Please accept all of the terms!" );
   return false;
   }

   if( document.frm.reason.value == "3" && document.getElementById("term1").checked == true && document.getElementById("term2").checked == true )
   {
   return true ;
   }
   else 
   {
   alert( "Please accept all of the terms!" );
   return false;
   }

 return( true );
}
```

The problem i have is that it does the validation good on the reason radio button but not on the terms checkboxes. Even if the right checkboxes are checked it stills asks to accept the terms... Does anyone see the mistake i have made? I am relative good in php but javascript is still something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your

```
document.frm.reason
```

is a collection of fields, so you cannot get its value straight away. document.frm.reason.value will return 'undefined'

Either fetch the fields directly using the ID

```
document.getElementById('1').checked
```

like so:

```
if(
    document.getElementById('1').checked && 
    document.getElementById("term1").checked &&
    document.getElementById("term2").checked && 
    document.getElementById("term3").checked) 
{
    return( true );
}
else 
{
    alert( "Please accept all of the terms!" );
    return false;
}
```

or use

```
document.frm.reason[0].checked
```

You also have a logical error in your code: you cannot get past the first if/else, since that part will always return true or false. So if don't check the first reason, you will always get `alert( "Please accept all of the terms!" );`.

You need to put those statements together in 1 big if/else statement

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KRUX4/

Comment: Thx for your answer and advice, however i just updated my code and for example if i thick reason id 3 i have to check term1 and term 2 but still i got an alert "Please accept all of the terms!"

Comment: EDIT: It worked did something very stupid! Thank you very mutch